# Pandas: Cannot do positional indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

Using census data from the United States Census Bureau. Counties are political and geographic subdivisions of states in the United States. This dataset contains population data for counties and states in the US from 2010 to 2015.

```
    cdf = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
    cdf = cdf[cdf['SUMLEV']==50]
    cdf.head()
    def answer_five():
        count = pd.DataFrame(cdf['STNAME'].unique(), columns =["State"])
        count['ct'] = 0
        i=0
        for item in cdf['STNAME']:
            if(item == count.iloc(i)['State']):
                count.iloc(i)['ct'] += 1
            else:
                i=i+1
        return count['State'] == count['State', np.max(count['ct'])]
    answer_five()
```

Can somebody please help me figure out the mistake in the if else statement nested in the for loop?
I want to solve it without using groupby

Comment: You should take a look at [Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). No need to do this by hand.

Comment: You can add and highlight the required output. It will help others to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

The iloc function in pandas uses brackets to get the actual value. Not parentheses. It should be:

```
if(item == count.iloc[i]['State']):
            count.iloc[i]['ct'] += 1
```